# Extra xml tag when using Lib:XSLT to create text file

Tags: perl, xslt

Cross-post http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=979710

I'm trying to create a text file from some XML using Perl and Lib::XSLT, my transformation works fine except Lib::XSLT adds an unwanted ?xml version tag to the start of the file, how can I stop it doing this?

Here's my XSLT:

```
<xslt:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:data="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xslt:param name="sep">|</xslt:param>
<xslt:output method="text" />
<xslt:template match="message:MessageGroup">
<xslt:for-each select="data:DataSet">
<!-- get dimensions (but not time) and store in dimensions variable -->
<xslt:for-each select="data:Series">
<xslt:variable name="dimensions">
<xslt:for-each select="data:SeriesKey">
<xslt:for-each select="data:Value">
<xslt:value-of select="@value" />
<xslt:value-of select="$sep" />
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:variable>
<!--get obs statuses and store in obs statuses variable-->
<xslt:variable name="obsStatuses">
<xslt:for-each select="data:Attributes">
<xslt:for-each select="data:Value">
<xslt:value-of select="@value" />
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:variable>
<!--write out dimensions variable, time, observation, obsstatuses variable-->
<xslt:for-each select="data:Obs">
<xslt:value-of select="$dimensions" />
<xslt:value-of select="data:Time" />
<xslt:value-of select="$sep" />
<xslt:value-of select="data:ObsValue/@value" />
<xslt:value-of select="$sep" />
<xslt:value-of select="data:Attributes/data:Value/@value"/>
<xslt:text>
</xslt:text>
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:for-each>
</xslt:template>
</xslt:stylesheet>
```

Here's the Perl:

```
use Lib::XSLT;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => "$xmlFile");
my $style_doc = $parser->parse_file(Path::Class::File->new("$xsltFile"));
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);
open OUTPUTFILE, ">>$outputFile" or die("Unable to open $outputFile, $!");
print OUTPUTFILE $stylesheet->transform($source);
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Comment: Please show your input and output. Also, it would seriously benefit you to look into XSLT templates and avoid all those nested for-eachs (which, in XSLT, are best avoided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the result of $stylesheet->transform() and using $stylesheet->output_file() fixes this issue, e.g:

```
use Lib::XSLT;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => "$xmlFile");
my $style_doc = $parser->parse_file(Path::Class::File->new("$xsltFile"));
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);
my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);
$stylesheet->output_file($results, $outputFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `<?xml>` declaration unwanted? It is valid XML and and has no influence on parsers.

Comment: The output I want is a plain text file delimited with "|", not XML.

Comment: Ah missed that :) you have an <xsl:output> element and an <xslt:output> element. Could they be conflicting?

Comment: I've tried removing the extra <xsl:output> tag but that didn't help :o/